# If you are homosexual would you enter heaven?

Tags: jannah, homosexuality

If you are homosexual would you enter heaven?

Comment: Is there any reason you would not? Being homosexual does not imply you have committed homosexual acts (slept with someone of the same sex). As far as I am aware, it is the homosexual acts not your sexual orientation for which is punished.

Answer (score 1):

No where in the faith will you find that *being* homosexual is forbidden. However, **acts of homosexuality** are explicitly forbidden.

Same for punishment, there is no punishment for *being* homosexual, but there is punishment for homosexual **intercourse.** And even then, punishment for sex-related crimes are almost impossible to catch. You need (obviously) an Islamic State with Sharia Courts, and multiple conditions/evidences of the crime such as witnesses to the explicit act of intercourse, etc.

As far as entering Heaven, it is all up to Allah. This includes everyone, homosexual or not. In short, being homosexual is not a sin/crime unless you act upon those urges, similar to non-marital sex, being heterosexual is not a sin/crime unless you commit Zina/Adultery.

And Allah knows best.